# Disable 640 mode ? (y/n)

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a shell script that will run in an automated batch system. During the script it prompts "640  mode ? (y/n)" where i have to hit y and [enter]. Does anyone know why it is it occurs when the "rm $File" command is ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `rm` is about to remove a file for which the current process does not have write permission.

To skip the question, run `rm -f $File`.

See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html, step 2b.

Comment: Thank you very much.. everything i google was popping up for the lumina 640 phone